# How to add and save name textfield to simple news block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I know that a similar question has been asked before but the problem that it doesn't have a complete answer for my question [In drupal how to add name textfield to simple news block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716405/in-drupal-how-to-add-name-textfield-to-simple-news-block)

```
function mymodule_simplenews_block_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 5) {
    $name = $form_state['values']['name'];
    // Do something here to store the name in the database
    // ...
    // ...

  }
}
```

I don't get the part which has to do with "Do something here to store the name in the database" . First, Should I add the name field to the simplenews_subscribers table ? How can I save the name field in the database ? I know that there is a simplenews_realname module but it is for Drupal 6.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add a field to an existing table in another module as this will likely break things when the time comes to upgrade. Instead create your own table in a custom module using [hook_schema](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_schema/7) and save the data there.

This [module developer's guide](http://drupal.org/developing/modules) will help if you're new to building Drupal modules.

Comment: So, is it OK to modify the other module and name it as mymodule or does this sound like a bad idea ? This appears to be a lot of code for such a small functionality ?

Comment: It's fine to modify the code in that other answer, yes. You're always going to have write more code when using a CMS framework like Drupal, it's built to be as generic as possible and a side effect of that is extra code complexity but far better extensibility and portability.